# Actionmailer not sending with gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

I am getting a Timeout::Error (execution expired): when trying to deliver an email using a gmail account. In my config/environments/development.rb, I have:

```
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :port                 => 587,
        :domain               => 'mydomain.com',
        :user_name            => 'me@mydomain.com',
        :password             => 'password',
        :authentication       => 'plain',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score -1):

Change 
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
to
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail